# Selenium, Java stale element reference with PageFactory

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

Hi all i've recently started learning selenium and I just made my first test. Sadly this tests is very flaky and fails about 30 % of the time due to:

> org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

I thought using the PageFactory.initElements was a way to combat this. Yet it does not seem to work. Here is how i've implemented it.

```
public class PageObject  {
    public PageObject() {
        final WebDriver webDriver = WebDriverManager.getDriverFromPool();
        PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(webDriver, 10), this);
    }
}

class Frontpage extends PageObject {
    @FindBy(id="search-results")
    private WebElement results;

    @FindBy(id="search")
    private WebElement searchBox;

    public Frontpage() {
        super();
    }

    public void resultPrinter() {
        List<WebElement> resultList = results.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        for(WebElement element : resultList) {
            System.out.println(element.getAttribute("id")); //this part is flaky
        }
    }

    public void searchForUser(String user) {
        searchBox.click();
        searchBox.clear();
        searchBox.sendKeys(user);
    }
}
```

and here is how its used:

```
public void userSearchTest() {
    Frontpage fp = new Frontpage();
    fp.searchForUser("Adam");
}

public void validateUserResult() {
    Frontpage fp = new Frontpage();
    fp.resultPrinter(); //fails here sometimes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by dynamic DOM.
When you launch the  `List<WebElement> resultList = results.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));` command it returns some list of elements according to the tagName you provided. However this occurs during the process of DOM building, so when you trying to iterate through these elements part of them may disappear / change so the element you are referencing to is no more exists.
The simplest way to work with dynamic DOM pages is each time the DOM / page is reloaded / rebuilt is to give some enough delay time and only after that to deal with it's elements.